# How to add Magento newsletter in footer?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm novice in Magento. I want to add newsletter option in footer and set newsletter functionality in footer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suppose you speak about the newsletter block to place it in the template.
A solution is to create a local.xml layout file in your theme.

For example, your theme is located at /app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/layout/local.xml

The local.xml has for advantage to allow you to overwrite core layout structure for your own template without the need to copy the whole newsletter.xml layout file of the base template.

Maybe you will need to remove the previous place of the newsletter block. I give you a sample of it below.

In this local.xml file you can do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>
        <remove name="left.newsletter" /> <!-- if you want to remove the newsletter block which is on the left side -->
        <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" as="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" before="-" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Then, in your footer.phtml, you should add the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter'); ?>
```

Comment: It worked. I use following code to call newsletter from footer.phtml. <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter'); ?>

Answer (score 17):

Just add below single line in you footer.phtml.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: This works well if you want to add it to a specific spot from inside a phtml file.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me gracefully.

Comment: Thanks, It made my night after 1 hour :D

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this with a static block in the back end with out going near the app code.  I think it is better to do it this way in case a Magento or an extension update overrides the edit.

#### Step 1

From the admin/backend of your store go to "CMS" nav menu at the top & select "Static Blocks". Click on "Add New" button.  In the subsequent form give a unique name to the "Block Title" & "Identifier" & make sure it's status is set to enabled.  Put the following code into the "Content" text area...

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Take note of the name you entered for the "Identifier" as you will need that in the next step.

Click on the "Save Block" button.

#### Step 2

Now go to CMS & "Pages" or "Static Blocks" depending on where you want to place the newsletter.  Select the “Content” tab & text area and add this code to anywhere where that you want to show the newsletter signup form...

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_identifier"}}
```

Be sure to put the name for identifier you used when creating the static block in `block_id`